# Android Compose Screen moves AlertDialog when onscreen keyboard appears

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-alertdialog, user-input

I have a Compose screen in my app that will show a Material3 AlertDialog when the user clicks a 'next' button. In that UI we ask if they want to add a label before they click the confirmButton and move on. The AlertDialog is using a TextField for the user input but since it's optional is often skipped and the user just wants to click the confirmButton and go next.

Our users that usually skip entering a label complain that the AlertDialog comes up in the center of the screen and then the onscreen keyboard comes up afterwards which moves the AlertDialog up on them. We do put focus on the TextField when it opens which is what triggers the keyboard. On our screens the dialog gets moved up just enough that the touch point where the button was before it moved ends up clicking outside the dialog and triggering the onDismissRequest.

Is there any way to still give focus to the TextField but constrain the AlertDialogs position or provide some other consistent click location for those users?

Comment: Can you share some screenshots before the keyboard opens and after the keyboard opens?